# Error when importing a zexp site that uses LinguaPlone

Tags: plone, linguaplone

I'm migrating a site from one zope instance to other using the import export tool. The site is using LinguaPlone (Products.LinguaPlone = 4.1.2). Both zope instances are identical because I use buildout and I have picked all eggs. But when migrating it shows the error:

```
Error Type: AttributeError
Error Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getTranslations'
```

I suppose that its the same error that was documented in http://plone.org/products/linguaplone/issues/241. How can I fix the site before migrating to the other zope instance?

The complete traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 620, in manage_importObject
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 642, in _importObjectFromFile
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 358, in _setObject
  Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.event, line 32, in objectEventNotify
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 113, in dispatchObjectMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 113, in dispatchObjectMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 113, in dispatchObjectMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 113, in dispatchObjectMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 262, in handleContentishEvent
  Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 188, in notifyWorkflowCreated
  Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 289, in notifyCreated
  Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 635, in _reindexWorkflowVariables
  Module Products.Archetypes.CatalogMultiplex, line 104, in reindexObject
  Module Products.Archetypes.ExtensibleMetadata, line 504, in notifyModified
  Module Products.LinguaPlone.utils, line 133, in generatedMutator
  Module Products.LinguaPlone.I18NBaseObject, line 221, in getTranslations
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getTranslations'
```

Comment: I'm not so certain that's the same problem. Could you share the *full* traceback?

Comment: Of course, I paste it in the question.

Comment: Is this one language or the whole site being exported / imported?

Comment: I tried to import the whole site.

Comment: Hrm, what is happening is that the reference to the canonical object is missing. Not that I've done any LP export/import step, ever, myself to easily suss out what is going wrong *here*.

Comment: Before doing it, I have imported a part of the site from another site, but it works. That means: first I created a site A, second I move part of it to a site B, and now I triying to move the whole site B to another zope instance C.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22330/discussion-between-daniel-hernandez-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: Could you move the data by copying the filestorage/blobstorage?

Comment: I can't move the filestorage because the source zope instance and the destine zope instance have more than one plone site.

Comment: Create a copy of Plone site, delete unnecessary sites from Data.fs, pack the Data.fs, then transfer this stripped down Data.fs for easy solution.

Comment: Thanks Mikko, but I want to "clean" the site to be exported/imported without problems.